When we say "roll out" a product, do we mean like a carpet or like a car?
"Roll out a product / feature / system" is a common expression, for example in project management, meaning, something is being introduced to the public for the first time.
I'm German, and we borrowed that expression into our own language, and now also talk about "ausrollen". That made me wonder, though: In English, wouldn't "to roll out a product" refer metaphorically to moving something on wheels from inside a building to the outside, like say, a car from a factory, a plane from a hangar etc?
In contrast, the loan translation into German would evoke the image of rolling out something like a carpet, i. e. unrolling something. If you think, for example, of unrolling a scroll, a map etc, that is not entirely off the mark (i. e. it is also a process of revealing something), but is that what a native speaker would associate with the original expression in English?

There’s also the possibility that the rollout  is just a metaphor for a variety of activities, which mayv

@Xanne - Yes, of course - the M-W definition makes that clear.

In Russian, the term influenced by English roll out is unambiguously wheel-type and not carpet-type.

It's interesting that this is an expression in other languages as well. In French, for a product, we would use "sortir", which means "get out" (as in leaving a room or a hangar, there is no concept of wheels/circles). We also have the "roll out" version, but for ideas or speech ("dérouler sa présentation"), not for tangible items (or semi-tengible like a product)

@WoJ French can also use lancer in order to premiere or debut or launch a new product, just as Spanish can use lanzar,  Portuguese lançar, and Italian lanciare, with all of those including English launch clearly sharing the same original etymon. But for movies and plays and other sorts of shows, basically things having grand openings and world premieres and such, the first public showing is apt to use other words altogether, like estreno < estrenar in Spanish and Catalan, or the related estreia < estrear in Portuguese.

Roll out (v.) This probably started life in the American West:
OED

5.U.S. colloquial.
**5.a.**intransitive. North American regional (western). To begin a journey; to leave. Also: to begin an enterprise.
1850 They hitched up and 13 men, 5 wagons and 23 Horses rolled out. L.
V. Loomis, Journal Birmingham Emigrating Co. 13

The quote seems, in its literal sense, to refer to the wagons rolling forwards.
The current use is relatively recent and from the motor industry: It retains the sense of a model of car being rolled off the production line and/or out of the factory to begin its journey to the customer:

6. transitive. Originally U.S. To introduce or launch (a new product, service, etc.). Cf. rollout n. Sometimes with the implication of
gradual or staged introduction.
1954 General Motors' second most productive division has rolled out a
real power package in this revival of a prewar speedster. Popular
Science June 102/1


So Autobot, roll out. just means Let's move.

@avpaderno The German equivalent would be "ausrollen", as already mentioned by the OP,  the literal translation of "roll (rollen) out (aus)/ rollout". "Let's move" carries a different meaning and wouldn't be "Autobot" in German.

@Mari-LouA I am not talking about any German equivalent. My previous comment is about a phrase Optimus Prime says in the Transformer movies (Autobots, roll out.) and more specifically to the roll out part of that phrase. I know about the Transformers sufficiently to know that Autobots are a faction of sentient robots and their name does not mean Let's move.

Sorry, but I'm to be forgiven if I am not a geek on the Transformer franchise, and maybe I wasn't the only one confused by your skeletal comment. But, please accept my apologies for the misunderstanding.

Car is close, but it refers to a production line.  Having "rolled out" a number of products both software and hardware for dozens of companies, we always referred to a production line.
Before rolling out, we are beta testing it (if software) or have a sample run (if physical items).  If you visualise a conventional production line, there is almost always  wheels or rollers involved such as a conveyor belt which moves on rollers.
From Britannica

The old system in which workers carried their parts to a stationary assembly point was replaced by the assembly line, in which the product being assembled would pass on a mechanized conveyor from one stationary worker to the next until it was completely assembled.


Right, to roll out and off the production line.

And the original production line was for... cars.

In my experience "rollout" in a software sense almost always refers to the process of incrementally transferring a large user base from an older product to a newer one, usually a small test group at first to make sure there's no major issues, then sequentially transferring large groups of users, usually by geographic region or business unit. That's the roll part, the way it moves across the userbase (whether physical or logical). At least in my experience, we wouldn't call it a rollout if everyone is impacted at once; that's just a deployment.

I can't say I've ever given much thought to what the expression suggests to me, but both Merriam-Webster and Collins give as their first American definition of 'rollout' as a noun 'the first public showing of an aircraft'. This suggests that 'wheeling a plane from a hangar' may indeed have been the original sense.

Noting that a 'plane in particular would be "wheeled out" rather than extracting itself from a hanger under its own power. More broadly, I'd suggest that this covers actions like bringing an item onto stage on a trolley... or for that matter manhandling a car onto a stage, or a carpet on a display stand :-)

The connection of roll out and new product  could come from  storing product in barrels.
I once had a pint of hard cider in a very tiny pub in Somerset near a crossroads where, in the 17th century, criminals were publicly hanged. The keg had run dry, so the barman went out to the storage shed, rolled out a new one, and placed  it in a hole in the wall.
https://youtu.be/j11MOncimNQ

The oleomargarine people seem to be driving a lively trade. In spite of legislative enactments against them in some of the states and municipal restraints in several of the cities, they continue to roll out their product by the ton.    [my emphasis]
Louisville Medical News,  10 April 1880.


It is possible that the airline company/constructors borrowed the famous line from the song itself. Etymonline dates "rollout" 1957 "action of wheeling out," originally of airplanes. The original Czech drinking song,  which was originally instrumental, had American lyrics added in 1934 and it was titled "Roll Out the Barrel".

@Mari-LouA: I think it was originally a polka rather than a drinking song?

@psmears My bad. Yes, it was originally a polka and then became a love song when  a Czech lyricist added lyrics to the melody.

As other answers explain, "roll out" usually refers to presenting something for the first time. However, there is a second meaning. The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary for example lists a second meaning:

​to make something flat by pushing something over it
Roll out the pastry.

Also, when putting out a red carpet for special visitors, the common phrase appears to be:

roll out the red carpet

So roll out can also have the meaning of unroll or make flat by rolling, similar to the German meaning mentioned in the Q.

Neither, like a barrel. It's from the drinking song Beer Barrel Polka with the lyrics
Roll out the barrel, we'll have a barrel of fun 
Roll out the barrel, we've got the blues on the run 
Zing boom tararrel, ring out a song of good cheer 
Now's the time to roll the barrel, for the gang's all here

traditionally sung at the beginning of parties.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This answer is essentially equivalent to the one already posted by TimR. The reference to rolling out barrels in this song would not be made if the practice of rolling out barrels had not existed beforehand.
